# Парсинг rozetka.com.ua

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый день.

Занимаюсь парсингом rozetka.com.ua. Недавно обнаружил, что на сайте есть возможность выбора региона (слева вверху), вот и захотелось посмотреть, какая разница в ценах и ассортименте. Может кто-то подсказать, какие и куда параметры передаются при выборе региона?

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

От выбора региона зависит доставка товара (способ, сроки и стоимость), меняется информация в правом блоке **Доставка**. На саму цену товара не влияет.

Для отслеживания, что и куда передаётся, рекомендую установить firefox+firebug.

Comment: Спасибо за firebug. Но все же, если абстрагироваться от того, на что именно это влияет, и так, судя по всему, передаются `visitor_city` и `__utmv`.